# Animating images in UIImageView takes too much memory

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using 150 images in a sequence for animation .

Here is my code.

NSMutableArray *arrImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

```
for(int i = 0; i <=158; i++)
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baby%05d.jpg",i]];
    [arrImages addObject:image];
}

babyimage.animationImages = arrImages;
[arrImages release];
```

babyimage.animationDuration=6.15;
    [babyimage startAnimating];

but it is taking too much memory.After playing it for 1 minute it shows memory warnings in console. and then crashed.i have reduced images resolution also and i can't make it less then 150 for better quality.

Is there any better way to do this animation without memory issue.
Thanks a lot 
plz help ...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baby%05d.jpg",i]]
```

use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baby%05d.jpg",i] ofType:nil]]
```

Reason is imageNames caches image and does not release until it release memory warning

### Edit

Also, don't store entire image into array, just save image name if you want or don't save anything. This will also take much memory.

Comment: this will not really help because the 150 images still need to be loaded into memory at once... they are not cached, but they are still retained by `arrImages`, so they won't be dealloc...

Comment: @sergio I am too having same functionality in my application and by this way my application crash is no more coming. I am running 250 images in loop, with each image of size 250 kb almost..

Comment: @P.J Thanks for reply. I have tried this but it takes too much time to load as all images load.BTW thanks a lot.

Comment: @P.J: I see. In any case I guess that if you inspect your app memory behaviour in Instruments you will find that it uses a lot of memory, so maybe your device is not crashing, but another one is... just a thought, because it is still true that the full set of images has to be loaded into memory and stay there until you release the images array. I agree that this is a huge improvement on using `imageNamed`, though, because in that case the app memory will shrink for the rest of its runtime.

Comment: @sergio Yes you are right, storing images in array is also taking much memory. Thanks for pointing that..

Comment: @Shashankshree Why are you storing images into array, store only image name

Comment: @Shashankshree Why dont you use NSTimer and change images after particular interval

Comment: @P.J i cant use NSTimer because i don't have time interval.I have to show 150 images in 6 sec to show as looks like video.

Comment: Its simple then, set NSTimer interval to (6/150).

Comment: @P.J By using NSTimer it solve memory issue but animation is not smooth now.even decrease interval .Not any other way to do such type of animation :( thanks for your responce .

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware as to what the animation is you haven't specified it. But if I were doing the code, I would follow the following algorithm.

This is assuming there's only one image shown at a particular time but during transition, you will end up having two convolving in a way.

```
procedureAnimate:
    photo_1 = allocate(file_address_array[i++])
    while i < MAX_PHOTOS
        photo_2 = allocate(file_address_array[i++])
        photo_3 = allocate(file_address_array[i++])
        perform_animation(photo_1, photo_2)
        release(photo_1)
        photo_1 = photo_2
        photo_2 = photo_3
    release(last_two)
```

I not sure if this is the_perfect_way of doing such a thing. But this will be a lot more efficient.

(May be there's something terribly wrong with the alloc/release login but this is consistent with my working at 5.14 AM in the morning). Let me know if this doesn't work.